# How to use "avconv" on raspberry pi for multicasting h264 file or /dev/video0?

Tags: raspberry-pi, multicast, avconv

I wrote an simple opencv desktop application to receive a multicast stream from my raspberry pi.
On the pi I want to use avconv to send the multicast.

This one works with my app and also with VLC-Player:

```
avconv -i video.mp4 -f mpegts udp://225.0.0.37:4030
```

But this one is not working:

```
avconv -i video.h264 -f mpegts udp://225.0.0.37:4030
```

Error Message as follows:

```
avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 16 2015 13:20:58 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
[h264 @ 0x8986980] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, h264, from 'video.h264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 320x240, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn
Output #0, mpegts, to 'udp://225.0.0.37:4030':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.20.4
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg2video, yuv420p, 320x240, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mpeg2video)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
[fps @ 0x8a5cac0] Discarding initial frame(s) with no timestamp.
    Last message repeated 445 times
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead -nan%
```

Could anybody explain where the problem is and how to solve this issue??

My aim is to get a live stream with the v4l2 driver, like this:

```
avconv -i /dev/video0 -f mpegts udp://225.0.0.37:4030
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use /dev/video0 with avconv you have to tell avconv that the source is an video4linux2 source/stream.

And for good results you have to tell v4l2 to set the resolution to ex.. 640x480 otherwise it's using 320x240

```
avconv -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -f mpegts udp://225.0.0.37:4030
```

but remember i think you have to purchase a mpeg2 license for that.

if you recompile avconv with the --enable-omx-rpi you can use the hardware h264 coder from the Openmax.

```
avconv -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -f mp4 -na \
-c:v h264_omx -b:v 750k udp://225.0.0.37:4030
```

-na = disable audio

This will Reduce the CPU usage from your pi by 70% or more.

For compiling instructions : 
https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/hardware-h264-video-encoding-with-libav-openmax-il/4997/6